# How to drop rows of a column having float datatype and are values less than 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new to pandas and I have just started to learn how to analyze a data.

In order to explain y problem,
Consider this table as df.csv

| Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 5.7 |
| B | 4 | 5.4 |
| C | 8 | 5.9 |
| D | 4 | 0.6 |

From this file, I want to drop the row that has Height less than 1 so that when i pass this command, it would delete the specified row and show me this:

| Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 5.7 |
| B | 4 | 5.4 |
| C | 8 | 5.9 |

I wrote this command:

```
dec = df[df['Height']<0.0].index
df.drop(dec,inplace=true)
df
```

but it is showing me this:

| Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 5.7 |
| B | 4 | 5.4 |
| C | 8 | 5.9 |
| D | 4 | 0.6 |

instead of :

| Name | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 5.7 |
| B | 4 | 5.4 |
| C | 8 | 5.9 |

is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dec = df[df['Height'] < 1.0].index
df.drop(dec, inplace=True)
```

True and False are written in capital letters and the check is needed for 1 and not for 0.